# rails mongodb find and delete duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid4

Is there a that I can make this algorithm faster?

I'm fetching all documents for this Model (Artifact) and for each document I would like to know if there is duplicate and if so I delete it.

```
   Artifact.all.to_a.each do |n|
      image = n.image_original
      thumb = n.image_thumbnail
      count_value =  Artifact.where(:image_original => image, 
                         :image_thumbnail => thumb).all.to_a.count
      if count_value > 1
        n.destroy!
      end
    end
```

Comment: Does the ordering matter (ie if 2 documents have the same values does it matter which one you destroy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `uniq` method on Artifacts collection like this:

```
@all_artifacts = Artifact.all
@distinct_artifacts = @all_artifacts.uniq {|artifact| artifact.image_original}
```

You can use `Criteria#distinct` like this `Artifact.distinct(:image_original)`, but this will only return distinct values with only that field.

Comment: thanks @Sharvy, I modify to include 2 fields `@distinct_artifacts = @all_artifacts.uniq {|artifact| artifact.image_original && artifact.image_thumbnail}@distinct_artifacts.count` =>`55905` instead of `64806`